# Windows 7 sound output through HDMI and Speaker at the same time

Tags: windows-7, audio, hdmi, sound-card, speakers

I would like to output the audio of a game through HDMI and through speakers at the same time.

I can only setup one default device. A solution I often find on the internet is using Wave Stereo Mix or something similar. My soundcard / soundcard driver does not support something like that.

I have heard that virtual audio cable should solve the problem, and I tried the trial version, but I have no clue how to set this up.

The reason for all this is (If someone is interested): I stream on sites like twitch.tv and use a dedicated streaming system with an avermedia USB3 capture device using HDMI. I can flawlessly mirror the image, but the sound is either going to my gaming headset or to my HDMI device. Both at the same time are not possible.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, windows does not support this feature. You'd have to have 2 physical sound cards to be able to do such a thing or, if you have a decent one, the option sometimes hides in the driver itself.

more information can be found [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/68534/how-do-i-enable-multiple-audio-outputs-on-windows-7), [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/329147/how-to-use-two-audio-devices-simultaneously-with-windows-7) and an old windows XP tutorial can be found [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r3ZYCiliK9o)

Good luck and have fun streaming!

Answer (score 0):

The following works free of charge if you want the same stereo (not surround) sound (no matter whether system sounds or sound from some program) on two different output devices at the same time and you do not have a "stereo mix" recording device:

- Install the free *Virtual Audio Cable Lite* version (not the trial version).
- Set the default sound output device to *Line 1* (the playback end of the *Virtual Audio Cable*).
   This is done in the context menu of *Line 1* on the Playback page of Sound settings.
- Mirror the *Line 1* recording device (the recording end of the *Virtual Audio Cable*) to one of your outputs:
   This is done in the Properties window of *Line 1* on the Recording page of Sound settings:
   Check *Listen to this device* and select one of the outputs in the list box.
- Use the *Audio Repeater* program included in *Virtual Audio Cable* to play Line 1 to the other output.
   I failed with the *Audio Repeater KS* (kernel streaming) version because of 100 % usage of one CPU core but I succeeded with the *Audio Repeater MME* (MultiMedia Extensions) version (no visible CPU usage).

Now playing audio to the default audio device will play to both of your audio devices at the same time, no matter whether sound from programs or system sounds. All programs work with this setup because all programs are able to play to the default sound output device.

If one of the sound outputs is a pluggable (USB) device and it is removed and plugged again, it automatically becomes the new default sound output device. That means every time the device is plugged, two of the above steps need to be repeated:

- the 2nd step: reset the default sound output device to *Line 1* (the Virtual Audio Cable).
- 3rd or 4th step: the one involving the device in question.