# Simultaneously playing on multiple audio devices

Tags: windows-7, audio

I am on Windows 7 and I have a monitor with audio capabilities connected via HDMI on the graphics card, a couple of speakers connected to the rear panel as well as a Bluetooth Headset.

I use a program called audio switcher to easily switch between the 3.
I am also familiar with VLC being able to select the audio device while having another audio device playing something  different.

The question is how can I simultaneously use 2 or all 3 audio outputs to play the same thing?

Comment: Check this link http://superuser.com/questions/329147/how-to-use-two-audio-devices-simultaneously-with-windows-7

Comment: Thanks but i was hoping for having it play the same sound simultaneously.